# Include parents in filtered recursive list

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

The goal is to filter a recursive list. When the user searches for Bar, Foo -> Bar should be displayed. Likewise when the search term is Baz, Foo -> Bar -> Baz should be included in the results.

[image]

My idea is to go through the results and add the parent (if any) to the results. But this must be done in a recursive fashion. Is there a simpler solution using linq? What are your thoughts?

What I've tried:

Playground: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaGQYokTnQPmRIHO

Main.razor

```
<MudTextField 
    T="string" 
    DebounceInterval="500" 
    Clearable="true" 
    Placeholder="Search" 
    Margin="Margin.Dense" 
    Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
    Adornment="Adornment.Start" 
    AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Filled.Search"
    ValueChanged="@(s => SearchTerm = s)"/>

<CascadingValue Value="Items.Where(i => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm)) ? i.Name.Contains(SearchTerm) : true).ToArray()">
    <ItemList Parent="0"/>
</CascadingValue>

@code {

    public string? SearchTerm { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Item[]? Items = 
    { 
        new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Foo", Parent = 0 },
        new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Bar", Parent = 1 },
        new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Baz", Parent = 2 },
    };
}
```

ItemList.razor

```
@foreach(var item in Items.Where(i => i.Parent == Parent))
{
    @if (Items.Where(i => i.Parent == item.Id).Any())
    {
        <MudNavGroup Title="@item.Name">
            <ItemList Parent="@item.Id"/>
        </MudNavGroup>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudNavLink Href="@("/items/" + item.Id)">@item.Name</MudNavLink>
    }
}        

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Parent { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter] public Item[]? Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item.cs

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public int? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems ok to me, but you could probably spare some performance by adding a supporting data structure. E.g. dictionary with items id as key, and parent `Item` as value. Thus you won't probably need the `Parent` field, and you'll be able to back-track all parents of an item by taking an id of a filtered item, get parent item from the dictionary, get its id and get its parent from the dictionary, and so on until you reach the root item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add function `Filter` or use appropriate name inside `@code` like below. And update `<CascadingValue Value="Filter(SearchTerm)">` Explanation is in comment.

```
<CascadingValue Value="Filter(SearchTerm)">
    <ItemList Parent="0"/>
</CascadingValue>

public Item[] Filter(string SearchTerm)
{
    // Get filtered list. Return all values when SearchTerm is null or empty else return matching values only
    var a = Items.Where(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm) || i.Name.Contains(SearchTerm)).ToList();

    // NOTE : Add children first then only search for parent
    // Use condition to find all children hierarchy of any object which is not exist in the list
    while (Items.Any(i => a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Parent) && !a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Id)))
    {
        // Add complete children hierarchy for selected iterms
        a.AddRange(Items.Where(i => a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Parent) && !a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Id)));
    }
    
    // Use condition to find parent of any object which is not exist in the list
    while (Items.Any(i => a.Any(x => x.Parent == i.Id) && !a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Id)))
    {
        // Add all parents who are not already added in list
        a.AddRange(Items.Where(i => a.Any(x => x.Parent == i.Id) && !a.Any(x => x.Id == i.Id)));
    }

    // return final object
    return a.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thx! Any idea how to also add the children? E.g. when the search result is Bar, include Foo and Baz.

Comment: So, if you search for `Bar` it should show all its complete hierarchy of its children?

Comment: Yep, that would be nice.

Comment: Updated the answer, Added first `while` to get complete children hierarchy for selected items. Then search for the parent hierarchy for all selected items.